# Home Back button in Navigation bar doesn't work in my android app

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar

After activating Navigation Up Button in Action Bar, Home Back button in Navigation bar doesn't work in my app. Where am I doing wrong? when I click on the navigation app up button, it works. But, Navigation back button as you can see on the pivture doesn't work...

[Back Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgIXy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzHlg.png@Override)

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_email:
            emailMenuItem();
            break;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            settingsMenuItem();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First understand following things:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    // executed this when hardware back button is pressed
}
```

is called when you press `back button`.

**AND**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // executed this when back button on Actionbar is pressed
            return true;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

is called when you press `back button` on `Actionbar`.

> Comment below if you have any queries.

Comment: I have learned the point and I corrected it. It works now. Thank you so much... :)